# Is std::array<int, 10> as class member zero-initialized?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray

```
struct MyClass
{
  std::array<int, 10> stdArr;

  MyClass() : stdArr()
  {}
};

MyClass c;
```

Questions:

1. Is `c.stdArr` zero-initialized?
2. If yes - why?

My own contradictory answers:

1. It is zero-initialized:
   `std::array` wants to behave like a c-array.
   If in my example above `stdArr` was a c-array, it would be zero-initialized by `stdArr()` in the initialization list. I expect that writing `member()` inside of an initialization list initializes the object.
2. It's not zero-initialized:

   - `std::array` normally has a single member which is in my case `int[10] _Elems;`
   - normally fundamental types and arrays of fundamental types like `int[N]` are not default-initialized.
   - `std::array` is an aggregate type which implies that it is default-constructed.
   - because there is no custom constructor which initializes `_Elems`, I think it is not zero-initialized.

What's the correct behaviour of `std::array` according to the C++11 Standard?

Comment: [CPP Reference says](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) that aggregate initialization works on `std::array`, i. e. elements **are** zero-initialized.

Comment: @H2CO3 The fact that aggregate initialisation works means that it can be initialised using `{ ... }` syntax. That isn't relevant here, there is no aggregate initialisation.

Comment: I linked another question that has complete explanation of when it is default-initialized and when it is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Is `c.stdArr` zero-initialized?

Yes

> If yes - why?

This performs a [**value initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of `stdArr`:

```
MyClass() : stdArr() {}
```

In this context, the effect of the value initialization is a [**zero initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) of the object.

**Edit**: there is plenty of relevant information in [*What are Aggregates and PODs...?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Comment: I would have expected that `: stdArr()` simply calls the std::array default constructor, which does nothing!?

Comment: @Martin85 that is not how it works. One would have to provide a user defined default constructor that does nothing (rendering `std::array` a non-aggregate in the process). This is a handle C++ gives us to zero-initialize PODs and aggregates.

Comment: [(Horrible) live example](http://ideone.com/Y8AXoM) (by no means a proof, I know)

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer and the links.

Comment: @gx_ in your tests, if we look at A1 and A2, they have non zero values when initialized by default. Which means you get zero-init only when using value initialization (`{}`). When you use default initialization (nothing, i.e. A1 and A2) you get random crap (no-init). be it `std array` or `c array`.

Answer (score 0):

"std::array wants to behave like a c-array" is not how the standard describes behavior. It's a user-defined type, and members of user-defined types are initialized by calling their constructor, i.e. `array<int,10>::array()`

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: Ok, let's better say, I want to behave std::array like a c-array. But am I right, you think `c.stdArr` is initialized in my code snippet? Thanks.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: It's not deleted, so it does have one: the compiler-generated one.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, then how does it work with initializer_list ?

Comment: @sasha.sochka it does not http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=32781f14670c8ccc79670abf2bca66f5-8dcf59174449f11e872bc3faded12b76.

Comment: @MSalters it's not callable in any way.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes for me this piece of code works. And it uses initializer_list
    `array<int, 5> a { {1,2,3,4,5}};`

Comment: @sasha.sochka no, it does use initializer_list. It's aggregate initialisation. See http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=0243724bed66c7d8c6d70275ba07a61e-8dcf59174449f11e872bc3faded12b76 and http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=7fc7cf92253d2f2aead7d08451346bec-8dcf59174449f11e872bc3faded12b76

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes, OK, but if it's an aggr. init., then there should be a public member which corresponds to underlying C-array.

Comment: Compare http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization with http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: @sasha.sochka only if you are implementing this in user code. `std::array` is required to be an aggregate, but the standard library can use compiler magic for this. Yes, a public array member is the simplest implementation, but not in any way the only one allowed.

Comment: @sasha.sochka the C++11 standard did not even specify that it must have a single array data member (although it presented an "example" using such an implementation).

Comment: Well, see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array: "This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array `T[N]` as its only non-static data member. It can be initialized with aggregate-initialization, given at most N initializers that are convertible to `T`: `std::array<int, 3> a = {1,2,3};`"

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: If the compiler generated `array<int,10>::array()` is not callable, then what is called in the statement `array<int,10>::array();` ? (Expression statement, creates temporary and immediately discards it.) "An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no **user-provided** constructors (12.1),"

Comment: @MSalters nothing. That's not a valid expression. You cannot call constructors directly. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b6f2b7a51de4ad1d03081e3ab95a6192-7063104e283ed82d51a6fde7370c6e59